# Should I use "los son" or just "son" for "they are"?

Tags: gramática, pronombres

Should I use "los son" or just "son" for "they are"?

> Por esta razón creo que hay un universo alternativo conectado al nuestro y pienso que **los son** conectados por nuestro clase de español. No voy a poder dormir esta noche.

Comment: Do check the answers, but in any case bear in mind that *los* is **not** a subject pronoun, as you would need here; the pronoun you're looking for is *ellos*.

Comment: @pablodf76 - I think you figured out what the OP was confused about and I wish you'd write a short answer based on your comment.  I think the two existing answers wandered off into unnecessary territory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Neither of them.

The correct answer is  just "**están**".

Firstly, you must use "están". "Ser conectado" does not make sense (unless it's a passive voice, which is not the case). Being connected is a possible state (state↔estar). They could get disconnected.

Secondly, you don't need lo or los, because you are already writing the word "connected". They are connected. "Lo" would be replacing the word "connected", but it is already there, so it has not been replaced.

```
You can say "Lo están" = "Están conectados".
```

But, since you're writing the word, then "lo" must not appear.

"Lo" does not replace the subject, because it is an object pronoun. It is replacing the atribute. Remember that "they" is "ellos", not "los".

One last thing, remember that "clase" is feminine:

> Por esta razón creo que hay un universo alternativo conectado al nuestro y pienso que **están** conectados por nuestr**a** clase de español. No voy a poder dormir esta noche.

Hope I helped.

Comment: Are you sure this is not a passive? It is followed by _por nuestra clase_

Comment: @mdewey I was sure because it says "los", and that's an object pronoun. You're right, we could also regard it as a passive. In such case, it'd be "ellos son conectados", or better "estos son conectados", but never "los", because it is an object pronoun, not a subject.

Comment: @mdewey - I'm guessing OP was trying to say "está conectado a nuestra clase."  I think OP was trying to write about a very imaginative thought, where something in an alternate universe was connected to their class.  However, your hypothesis does seem plausible to me.  One could write such a sentence and, done right, sure, it would hold together.  Personally, I'd give it a 5% probability that's what OP had in mind.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to say "they are (so connected)" you can use the neuter attributive *lo* (distinct from the masculine, and never pluralized regardless the reference).

However, because you put in the predicate adjective *conectados*, you can not use it, and thus you should just put say "son" or, if you really want another word, "ellos son"

Comment: I wanted to edit this to make it clearer but I couldn't understand what you were trying to say.  For starters, what is "so connected"?